# Word for emphasizing very less price

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Though I bought this sofa for $2000, I had to sell it for **just** $150.

Can we replace the word **just** with the alternatives like **mere** or **sheer**?

New sentences will be like under.

1. Though I bought this sofa for $2000, I had to sell it for ***mere*** $150.
2. Though I bought this sofa for $2000, I had to sell it for ***sheer*** $150.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence should be rendered as "for a mere $150." or "for merely $150."

(Note that "mere" is an adjective modifying $150, and "just" (in this context) and "merely" are adverbs modifying "sold (for)".)

The second sentence doesn't parse for me.

(I am a native speaker.)